# Finding three 3x3 Hermitian matrices which anticommute and squares to identity.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to find three 3x3 matrices which anti-commute and squares to identity?

The best method I thought of was to take a general hermitian matrix. Find the constraints(1) on its elements such that it squares to identity.

And then, take a hermitian matrix which we know squares to identity like for eg:A={{1,0,0},{0,0,1},{0,1,0}} and find the constraints(2) so that a general hermitian matrix anti commutes with it.

A matrix which satisfies both constraints (1)and (2) will anti-commute with A as well as will scale to identity.

Is this the easiest method to find such matrices?

Comment: There aren't such matrices. $$AB + BA = 0 \implies \det(A)\det(B) = \det(AB) = \det(-BA) = (-)^n\det(B)\det(A)$$ If two $n\times n$matrices anticommute and $n$ is odd, at least one of them is not invertible.

Comment: The question is confusing. It says "scales to identity" (what does that mean? a scalar matrix?) in some places and "squares to identity" in some others.

Comment: @user1551 sorry, i have edited my question

Comment: @achillehui are such matrices possible when n is even?

Comment: @RajathKrishnaR The technical term of what you're looking for is a Clifford algebra representation. Your specific representation is possible as $2\times 2$ matrices, and are given by the [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices). From the Pauli matrices, you can construct $2k \times 2k$ representations for any $k$, simply by direct sum, but these representations are not irreducible.

Comment: If by squares to identity, you mean $A^2 = B^2 = I_n$, then the answer is yes. The simplest example are the [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices).

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of the Pauli matrices. I wanted to know whether we can have such matrices for higher n. My ultimate aim is to make a complete operator basis for the vector space of all 3*3 hermitian matrices. But, the basis should be such that at least two of the basis matrices anti-commute and the same two matrices when squared should give identity.

Comment: Now, from the comments it is clear that for 383 it is not possible. Bit, can I form such a complete operator basis for the vector space of 4*4 hermitian matrices??

Comment: @Rajath If I understand the requirements correctly, yes. You can do this for any even dimension; just create a block diagonal matrix with Pauli matrices on the diagonal.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom but, I don't think matrices created in that way will anti-commute, will they? I was checking in mathematica and it doesn't seem so?

Comment: If you mean that every pair of basis elements should anticommute, then that's a different story

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I want a basis in which atleast two of the basis elements anti-commute and I want the same two to give identity when squared.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ anticommute and square to the identity, then the same can be said for
$$
\tilde A = \pmatrix{A&0\\0&A}, \quad \tilde B = \pmatrix{B&0\\0&B}
$$

Comment: More generally, you can define $\tilde A = I \otimes A$ where $\otimes$ is the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40177/discussion-between-rajath-krishna-r-and-omnomnomnom).